# Is it possible to capture HTTP/3 (QUIC) traffic with Fiddler Proxy? (Fiddler Classic)

Tags: fiddler, http-proxy, http3

I have a long time setup which is capturing and decrypting HTTPS using Fiddler Proxy, I use my jailbroken phone so I can go around certificate pinning also and run it thru this proxy to capture traffic and analyze request/responses for different apps.  I love Fiddler because it allows me to modify content on the fly at will to find issues.  Today I ran into an app that is not behaving nicely and after some hours of research it seems my issue is because the app is using HTTP/3 and I haven't been able to make it work.  Am I just barking at the wrong tree here? Is it even possible to capture such traffic with Fiddler Proxy? any alternatives with same like features that I could use? I'm not expert on protocols and certificates, etc. so please bear with me on the question :-).  Thanks to any gurus out there that can help!

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

As of right now, AFAIK there are no HTTP debugging proxies that support HTTP/3. For Fiddler specifically, they only shipped HTTP/2 support a few months ago (Jan 2022, 7 years after HTTP/2 was standardized) and only in Fiddler Everywhere. There's no mention of any timeline for shipping it in Fiddler Classic I can see, maybe never.

I can't speak for the Fiddler team's reasons, but I also maintain a debugging proxy and the general problem is that most languages don't yet have stable libraries available to easily handle HTTP/3, which makes it very difficult to support. There's some background on the causes of this here: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2021/10/25/the-quic-api-openssl-will-not-provide/. There are some experimental implementations available now, but in most cases nothing that's easy to integrate and reliable, unlike HTTP and HTTP/2 (normally provided as part of programming languages' core libraries, often with many battle-tested userspace implementations available too).

From the HTTP/2 approach, I would guess that HTTP/3 support in Fiddler is a couple of years away at least and will only be coming to Fiddler Everywhere, not to Fiddler Classic (but I don't know for sure - you'd have to ask them).

In the meantime, the best workaround available is to block HTTP/3 traffic entirely. Well-behaved clients should fallback to HTTP/1 or 2 automatically. Blocking all UDP packets on port 443 using a firewall will generally be sufficient (it can be used on other ports, but I've never seen it in practice).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim for taking the time to shed some clarity :-) .. I found some articles about blocking QUIC on the UDP ports and tried but it didn't seem to work.  It is entirely possible tho that I didn't do it correctly and gave up too fast .. I'll give it another try.